# Stop automatic change of y axis range in dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Consider the example on this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6xbj847x/1/

HTML:

```
Graph
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    [
        [0, 1],     // Starts at height 1, step width is 2
        [2, 2],     // step width is 1
        [3, 3],     // step width is 0.5
        [3.5, 4],   // step width is 0.25
        [3.75, 5],  // remainder is at height 5
    ],
    {
        stepPlot: true,
        labels: ["XX","YY"],
        series: {
            "YY": {stepPlot: true}
        }
    });
g.ready(function() {
    g.setAnnotations([
    {      
      series: "YY",
      x: 0,
      shortText: "2"
    },
    {      
      series: "YY",
      x: 2,
      shortText: "1"
    },
    {      
      series: "YY",
      x: 3,
      shortText: ".5"
    }
    ]);    
  });
```

When it is shown at start, the y axis shows a range of 0 to 5:

[image: range 1]

Then I do an "X" zoom: left click mouse a bit before x=2; while clicked drag to the right, then release somewhere after x=2; the graph updates, and the x range is updated as expected:

[image: range 2]

... but also the y axis automatically updated, and now it shows the range of 0 to 3 (or thereabouts)!

How can I prevent this automatic update of the y axis upon select-zoom in dygraphs - so it always the initial y axis range which is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it:

http://dygraphs.com/options.html

> valueRange #
>
> Explicitly set the vertical range of the graph to [low, high]. This may be set on a per-axis basis to define each y-axis separately. If either limit is unspecified, it will be calculated automatically (e.g. [null, 30] to automatically calculate just the lower bound)

So, the solution is:

```
var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    [
        [0, 1],     // Starts at height 1, step width is 2
        [2, 2],     // step width is 1
        [3, 3],     // step width is 0.5
        [3.5, 4],   // step width is 0.25
        [3.75, 5],  // remainder is at height 5
    ],
    {
        stepPlot: true,
        labels: ["XX","YY"],
        series: {
            "YY": {stepPlot: true}
        },
        valueRange: [0, 5.5], // fix y range axis here, so it does not autoupdate on zoom
    });
g.ready(function() {
    g.setAnnotations([
    {      
      series: "YY",
      x: 0,
      shortText: "2"
    },
    {      
      series: "YY",
      x: 2,
      shortText: "1"
    },
    {      
      series: "YY",
      x: 3,
      shortText: ".5"
    }
    ]);    
  });
```